# Google Closure compiler: class as function argument

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I can't figure out how to send class references as function arguments, so that Google Closure compiler will compile it right in advanced mode. In the below example I send a class reference to the Test1.doSomething function, which invokes a static function on the class. I've set the @param to Function, because I guess it still is a function, although I use ES6 style classes. Is there some other keyword I should use?

The below code works fine uncompiled, and also works fine if I go old school and change "class Test2" into "function Test2()". I've also tried to change the @param into function(), function(new:Test2), function(this:Test2), typeof Test2, etc, with no success.

```
class Test1
{
    /**
     * @param {!Function} typeRef   
     */    
    doSomething(typeRef)
    {
        typeRef.doSomething();
    }
}

class Test2
{
}

Test2.doSomething = function()
{
    alert(1);
}

var t1 = new Test1();
window["t1"] = t1;
t1.doSomething(Test2);
```

I compile as follows:

```
--debug --formatting=PRETTY_PRINT --language_in ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT --language_out ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js Test.js --js_output_file Script.js
```

The result with "class Test2"

```
'use strict';
class $Test1$$ {
}
window.t1 = new $Test1$$;
```

The result with "function Test2()"

```
'use strict';
class $Test1$$ {
  $doSomething$($typeRef$$) {
    $typeRef$$.$doSomething$();
  }
}
function $Test2$$() {
}
$Test2$$.$doSomething$ = function $$Test2$$$$doSomething$$() {
  alert(1);
};
var $t1$$ = new $Test1$$;
window.t1 = $t1$$;
$t1$$.$doSomething$($Test2$$);
```

EDIT ON 29 JAN: Added a more complete example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Car
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.make = "Ford";
        console.log("Car created.");
    }
}
Car.create = function(registry)
{
    let obj = new Car();
    registry.add(obj);
    return obj;
}

class Motorcycle
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.make = "BMW";
        console.log("Motorcycle created.");
    }
}
Motorcycle.create = function(registry)
{
    let obj = new Motorcycle();
    registry.add(obj);
    return obj;
}

class Registry
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.vehicles = [];
    }
    add(vehicle)
    {
        this.vehicles.push(vehicle);
    }
    makeVehicle(typeRef)
    {
        typeRef.create(this);
    }

}

function init()
{
    var registry = new Registry();

    registry.makeVehicle(Car);
    registry.makeVehicle(Motorcycle);
    registry.makeVehicle(Motorcycle);
    registry.makeVehicle(Car);
    registry.makeVehicle(Car);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass in a class, you can use the [`{typeof namespace}`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System) type:

```
@param {typeof Test2} TypeRef
```

As in your code:

```
class Test1
{
    /**
     * @param {typeof Test2} TypeRef   
     */    
    doSomething(TypeRef)
    {
        (new TypeRef()).doSomething();
    }
}

class Test2
{
  doSomething ()
  {
    alert(1);
  }
}

var t1 = new Test1();
window["t1"] = t1;
t1.doSomething(Test2);
```

[Demo (don't forget to hit Compile)](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Aclass%2520Test1%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F**%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Btypeof%2520Test2%257D%2520TypeRef%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%252F%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520doSomething(TypeRef)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520(new%2520TypeRef()).doSomething()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%250A%250Aclass%2520Test2%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520doSomething%2520()%250A%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520alert(1)%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%250A%250Avar%2520t1%2520%253D%2520new%2520Test1()%253B%250Awindow%255B%2522t1%2522%255D%2520%253D%2520t1%253B%250At1.doSomething(Test2)%253B)

When using `@param` (without `typeof`) you would pass an instance of that type*. This is far more common than passing a class itself

*: Sorry if this is not relevant but I noticed a couple of issues in the original code and wanted to show you how to fix them, even if not relevant;

To produce an instance-typed version, I had to change 3 things;

1) The `Test2.doSomething` assignment should be assigning to `Test2.prototype`;

```
Test2.prototype.doSomething = function()
{
    alert(1);
}
```

Or using the ES6 Class format:

```
Test2 
{
    doSomething() 
    {
         alert(1);
    }
}
```

2) And to resolve a warning `Test1.doSomething`'s `@param` annotation had to become `Type2`, as Function does not declare a `Function.doSomething` method.

```
/**
 * @param {!Type2} typeRef   
 */
```

3) The final line passes the class itself, not an instance of the class, so you should use the `new` operator to send in an instance of that class.

```
t1.doSomething(new Test2());
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Graham! My original code had Test2.doSomething as a static function, and that is an important requirement. I simplified my example to make it short. Imagine if you have 10 classes that each have a static factory function to create objects of those 10 types. But you don't call those factory functions directly, you instead pass a class reference to another function which in turn invokes the factory function. That's my scenario. I tried using the "typeof" keyword as you suggested, but still can't get the code to work in my scenario. I can give you a more complete example if you want.

Comment: @BjörnMorén That makes sense. I think what you'd need is to define an interface that your classes all share. A more complete example would be helpful. I think most often I'd do the `new`ing before passing the object.

Comment: Hi Graham. I added a more detailed example. It is the general principle of how to annotate the type information I'm looking for, because as the code stands it doesn't make much sense. The production code is much more complex, but I didn't want to overwhelm with details.